# Grunt browserify does not apply uglifyify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify

My Grunt config:

```
 browserify: {
            options: {
                transform: [
                    ['babelify', {presets: ['react', 'es2015']}],
                    'uglifyify',
                     'browserify-shim'],
                browserifyOptions: {
                    debug: true
                }
            },
            [jsDir + 'bundle.js']: srcDir + 'js/**'
        },
```

I have installed `uglifyify` via `npm` but code is still not mimified.

Is it setup properly or is there other reason why it does not work?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes. Throwing out Grunt :) It is dead.

Comment: Do you have an alternative that you're using?

Comment: Yeah. For application projects Webpack has been standard tool for some time. For libs you can try rollup.

Comment: Webpack or Browserify(without Grunt!!) I'm currently using grunt-browserify (even for libs!!!)